# Application deployed via windows store

Tags: c#, store

I am considering deploying my application via the windows store apart from the traditional website download (via an msi).

I created the appx package with the Desktop App Converter tool.

The application does some updates checks, and when being deployed via the windows store I would like to disable such checks.

The question is how to detect if the application was deployed via normal msi or via the windows store.

Comment: usually you must make a number of modifications to submit to the store, but if your codepage is absolutely identical use `GetCurrentPackageFamilyName`

Answer (score 0):

To add to nikos' comment, `GetCurrentPackageFamilyName` will return an error `APPMODEL_ERROR_NO_PACKAGE` if it's run outside the UWP context (i.e. the MSI scenario you mention).

Note that this API is dependent on Windows 8 or greater, which will preclude the app from running on Windows 7. Your can work around this by dynamically loading the API. More info [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446598(v=vs.85).aspx)